# EF Core - Check if a UDT exists with raw sql gives wrong return value

Tags: c#, sql, database, ef-core-5.0

I'm trying to check if a UDT already exists

```
public static bool TypeExists(DbContext dbContext, string typeName, string schema = "dbo")
{
    string sql = @$"Select  1 HAVING TYPE_ID('{schema}.{typeName}') IS NOT NULL";

    return dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw(sql) > 0; 
}
```

The method will return -1 in my case. I do not know why it does not return 1 => I've ensured that the UDT exists in the database

The TSQL `Select  1 HAVING TYPE_ID('dbo.Memo') IS NOT NULL` will return one line as expected.

Any ideas to solve my problem?

Comment: Apart from using an EF context, this has nothing to do with EF itself, please use proper tags. What returns -1? The SQL query returns 1 or null. `TypeExists` returns a bool.

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns -1. Per definition the return value is a integer not nullable. I guess this is why it does not return `null`. But it should not matter as it should return 1.

Comment: Oh yeah. It returns the number of rows affected. No rows are affected by a Select (even when rowcount > 0) . EF core has reduced the options for executing raw SQL. Use plain ASP.Net.